# What is default list styling (CSS)?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

On my website I use reset.css. It adds exactly this to list styles:

```
ol, ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

The problem is that all list styles are set to `NONE` with this. I want to revert back original list styles (default) for all lists on website sub-pages only (all lists in `.my_container`).

When I try settings things like `list-style-type` to `inherit` is doesn't inherit the browser's default styles just for this CSS property.

**Is there any way to inherit the original browser's styles for certain properties without modifying reset.css?**

Comment: reset.css is one of the worst anti-patterns in web design.

Comment: @Péter Varga Huh? Why? It works perfect for my needs. I create highly modular websites and reset.css is something I have to use.

Comment: Rather than a full-on reset stylesheet, consider something like https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css which sets sensible defaults for all elements. That way, you start with a baseline across all browsers and can build out from there. Also, you don't have to add extra code to get back to the default settings!

Comment: @OllyHodgson Yes, but I've got specific reasons why I want to use reset.css. I need to actually clear as much style as possible and I want to re-write it - not the other way around :)

Comment: If you want erase them and rewrite them, what's the point of this question? As far as I can see you have two options: 1) specifically avoid resetting list styles so you keep the defaults 2) reset them, and come up with your own list styles.

Comment: @BoltClock - Just to clarify - I want to give users opportunity to build their own list from scratch (I added class for each possible style) - I was only wondering if there is something like "default" setting but since there isn't any default styling - I'll just create one.

Comment: This questions title does not really match the question in the text.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

I used to set this CSS to remove the reset :

```
ul { 
   list-style-type: disc; 
   list-style-position: inside; 
}
ol { 
   list-style-type: decimal; 
   list-style-position: inside; 
}
ul ul, ol ul { 
   list-style-type: circle; 
   list-style-position: inside; 
   margin-left: 15px; 
}
ol ol, ul ol { 
   list-style-type: lower-latin; 
   list-style-position: inside; 
   margin-left: 15px; 
}
```

EDIT : with a specific class of course...

Comment: It does not “revert back original list styles (default)”. It just sets *some* styles.

Comment: I agree, but whatever the way, the goal was just to set some style. This CSS give a pretty basic style to lists, no more.

Comment: There is no "default" option for list-style-type and I found out that after getting answers. Browsers just add some styles which are often not consistent between browsers.

Comment: I also had someone set display: inline-block; and it appears it needs to be list-item to make the bullets show again.

Comment: This does not really answer the "What is default list styling" from the questions title.

Answer (score 36):

I think this is actually what you're looking for:

```
.my_container ul
{
    list-style: initial;
    margin: initial;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}

.my_container li
{
    display: list-item;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think that this answer something important too. `inherit` inherits the styles from the parent containers and it doesn't set them to the default browser values. `initial` does this (I found out about its existence later on) but are you sure that `ul { list-style: initial; }` and `ol { list-style: initial; }` will produce a valid outcome? Doesn't it set `list-style` to its initial value regardless of the element it is applied to? Won't the `initial` value be `disc outside none` for both types of lists?

Comment: Amazing, `initial` never occurred to me!

Comment: `initial` is not supported in any versions of IE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#keywords

Comment: This does not really answer the "What is default list styling" from the questions title.

Answer (score 15):

As per the documentation, most browsers will display the `<ul>`, `<ol>` and `<li>` elements with the following default values:

**Default CSS settings for [UL](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) or [OL](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ol.asp) tag:**

```
ul, ol { 
    display: block;
    list-style: disc outside none;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}
ol { 
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

**Default CSS settings for [LI](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp) tag:**

```
li { 
    display: list-item;
}
```

**Style nested list items as well:**

```
ul ul, ol ul {
    list-style-type: circle;
    margin-left: 15px; 
}
ol ol, ul ol { 
    list-style-type: lower-latin;
    margin-left: 15px; 
}
```

**Note:** The result will be perfect if we use the above styles with a class. Also see different [List-Item](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp) markers.

Comment: If this were the case, then nested list will have a top and bottom margin added with any new level.

Answer (score 11):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp

```
ul { 
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: thanks saved my life, was wondering why the hell was there padding in my submenu.

Comment: This will add vertical.margij on any nested list.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. Whenever there is any style sheet being applied that assigns a property to an element, there is no way to get to the browser defaults, for any instance of the element.

The (disputable) idea of reset.css is to get rid of browser defaults, so that you can start your own styling from a clean desk. No version of reset.css does that completely, but to the extent they do, the author using reset.css is supposed to *completely* define the rendering.

Answer (score 3):

An answer for the future: CSS 4 will probably contain the revert keyword, which reverts a property to the initial value it had from the user-agent stylesheet or from user styles (or to the value inherited from a parent, if present) [[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert)].

As of writing this, only Safari supports this – [check here](http://caniuse.com/#search=revert) for updates on browser support.

In your case you would use:

```
.my_container ol, .my_container ul {
    list-style: revert;
}
```

See also [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36256886) with some more details.

Answer (score 2):

You're resetting the margin on all elements in the second css block. Default margin is 40px - this should solve the problem:

```
.my_container ul {list-style:disc outside none; margin-left:40px;}
```