# overflow:hidden on div in ordered list affects li, Chrome bug?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm inclined to think this is a bug in Chrome (why would a style on a child element affect the parent?), but there might be something else going on that I'm not understanding.

The ordered list below has 1 item, which in Firefox and IE10 is numbered (although in IE, it's positioned wrong).  In Chrome though, the number is hidden entirely.

```css
ol {
  list-style-position: outside;
}
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <div>Some text that trails off</div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

What's going on/is this a bug/can this be worked around?

Comment: Do you require overflow:hidden on the div? Is this necessary. If you remove it you can see the number in chrome.

Comment: @lharby This was simplified from code that has 2 divs in the li, and involves `text-overflow: ellipses`

Comment: @LuisP.A. "upper" doesn't exist

Comment: @Izkata..yes you are right, my mistake . Is  decimal

Comment: @LuisP.A. All that does is set it to use numbers, which is the same as the default for `<ol>`

Comment: It depends how you want to attack it then, would a js solution be OK? I use  this http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/ it adds a class to the html which allows you to write vendor specific css. so .firefox ol { //your code here }, modernizr also uses this technique, but that might be very heavy. Otherwise I suppose you might need a conditional stylesheet. Was looking here but it's quite dirty: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/

Comment: @Izkata..sometimes we need to force the style...this is why -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737266/what-is-default-list-styling-css . just a precaution.

Comment: @LuisP.A. Luckily our reset.css does not include that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is a kind of a hack, but it works. Adding a pseudo `:before`-element brings back the list style, as the `li` will have some content now. Bring back the `div` to the top and it looks like nothing has changed.

**CSS**

```
ol > li:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
}

div {
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/7gco04ee/)

Comment: ..this has me going WTF even more, but it works completely.  Firefox and Chrome both look the same now.

Comment: So I undid this and added some text in the <li> but outside the "overflow:hidden" div, and the number for that <li> reappeared.  Does Chrome/Webkit have some secret psuedo-property akin to IE's `hasLayout`, that "overflow:hidden" undoes?

Comment: Basically my solution does excactly what you have done manually by inserting some content. It seems that Webkit has a problem, when only block-level elements (even `inline-block` is working) with `overflow:hidden;` appear. My answer is a workaround to add some invisible content, without destroying the layout.

Comment: In my case, I solved this problem by adding
`list-style-position: inside` on list block

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a bug so to speak, more of a difference in how different browser engines render the CSS. (Blink vs Trident vs Gecko vs WebKit etc)

Technically speaking, the Chrome display is correct due to hiding everything outside of the `div` as specified with `overflow: hidden;`.

If you use the Chrome Inspector, you can see where the edges of the elements are and the number is outside of that area.

Your best work-around would be to set an additional piece of CSS to override the main div element.

```css
ol {
  list-style-position: outside;
}
div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
ol div {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>

  <ol>
    <li>
      <div>Some text</div>
    </li>
  </ol>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The number should be on the `li`, though, not the div AFAIK.  And the `overflow: hidden` is intentionally on the div, to use `text-overflow: ellipses` in the original

Comment: It really depends on how the browser renders. A block level element is 100% of the width and clears both left and right. Chrome obviously interprets that within an `li` differently to FireFox.

Comment: The list marker exists separately from the principal box when list-style-position is outside. See the [propdef](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/generate.html#propdef-list-style-position) and my answer to the duplicate question. So technically the list marker isn't overflowing the div, because it's not a descendant of the div in the first place, and therefore clipping should not be happening. If Chrome is making the list marker a descendant of the div, then Chrome is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the div inside li, display the div as inline, otherwise list-style: inside will work.

```css
ol {
  list-style-position: outside;
}

div {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 150px; display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li><div>Some text</div></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: `display: inline` won't work; I've edited the question with more of the original

Comment: This works for the original post and edited and is a working solution for the revised question. Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Define selectors for these elements.

Your going to began to run into problems if your just using global tags: `<li> <div>` especially since your nesting here.

*eg:*`<li class="dothis"> <div class="thisdivdoes"> ...`

After you do this it would be easier to differentiate `overflow:hidden;` where and not where.

Since your  tag is within your `<li>` define what you want them to do individually since that's what you want to do, or else you may see them inherit each other as your experiencing.

Also, check your doctype in HTML5 I think it's not valid while in strict it may be.

Comment: The question is a [simplified example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's nowhere close to what I'm actually using