# How do I make the OL override the list-style it was assigned to respect the type property

Tags: css, css-selectors

The situation is that one of the stylesheet that comes with the theme has this `ol { list-style: decimal; }`. However, for this specific page, I want it to use the style defined by the `type` property of `ol` element.

Eg

```
<ol type='a'>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ol>
```

or

```
<ol type='i'>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ol>
```

I tried `ol { list-style: initial}` and `ol { list-style: inherit}`, but no luck.

Can someone give me a way to reset the applied style this using CSS?

Comment: How are your stylesheets ordered?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737266/what-is-default-list-styling-css, it might be what you are looking for

Comment: @CarlEdwards My styles would be inline on the page. So this would have the most priority over others.

Comment: @randomguy04 Thanks, that wasn't quite I was hoping for. Sorry, I updated the question just now

Comment: but decimal is the default value for <ol>, aren't you confusing <ol> with <ul> ?

Comment: @SuthanBala Inline styling takes priority over anything defined in a stylesheet so are you sure you it written that way. An example would be this: `<ol type='a' style="list-style: initial">...</ol>`

Comment: @randomguy04 Assigning the type property to `ol` would change the default to the specified type https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

Answer (score 1):

When CSS property is defined in user styles globally, there is no way you can change this style from HTML attribute because of how [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) is calculated.

**list-style-type: initial** Doesn't work either, it is used to reset to a browser, not theme default value.

So you'll have to write your own, more specific CSS.
For this use case, you can  use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Then the result would be something like this:

#### HTML

```html
 <ol type='a'>
   <li>first</li>
   <li>Second</li>
 </ol>
 <ol type='i'>
   <li>first</li>
   <li>Second</li>
 </ol>
```

#### CSS

```css
/* Theme defined stylse */
ol {
  list-style: decimal;
}

/* Your page defined list */
ol[type='a'] {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}
ol[type='i'] {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
}
```

---

You can play with this code in codepen ([codepen.io/Xopoc/pen/yPQBEM](https://codepen.io/Xopoc/pen/yPQBEM))

Answer (score 0):

The type attribute was deprecated in HTML4 and re-introduced in HTML5 [1]. It really shouldn't be used unless in legal documents. Ideally, you would override this in CSS. However, you can override the type attribute for a ordered list by putting a different type on each li [2]:

```
<ol type='i'>
  <li type="a">first</li>
  <li type="a">Second</li>
</ol>
```

As far as your example goes, here is a fiddle showing this technique working:

https://jsfiddle.net/jd5378mg/1/

Resources for refference:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li