# Spacing at top of ul

Tags: html, css

I haven't written any code yet (for this project), but have noticed in previous coding ventures that when I try to make a dropdown menu with an unordered list, there is unwanted padding between the top of the containing div and the list, which is displayed in inline format. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Please, bring some code with your issue so we can work on it.

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: Without reading further, `I haven't written any code yet ` is usually a big no-no on SO.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That is default browser styling. A handful of different HTML elements come with them. Ordered and unordered lists being two of them. Also header tags. [Here is another SO question that addresses your concerns.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737266/what-is-default-list-styling-css)

You just have to overwrite the styles. One thing to mention is that the default browser styles could be different in different browsers so have a look at your app in a few browsers.

This worked on Firefox
```

```
ul {
      padding: 0 0 0 0;
      margin: 0 0 0 0;
    }
```

```

Comment: I've tried overwriting the margins and padding. Also tried "list-style:none".

Comment: I have downvoted because answering such a question will encourage further very low quality questions.

Comment: @ggdx No need to downvote me. It's a legitimate question.

Comment: @nameless, check to make sure your css rule is the same as the rule being applied in that specific browser

Comment: For supporting new joinees. upvoting u@MaxBaldwin

Comment: I'm using Firefox.

Comment: @ggdx, that's not true.

Comment: @ggdx Is that necessary ? The OP has just joined. How can you expect a high quality question from him .Just guide him to right path.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin I afforded you the courtesy of explaining the downvote. I didn't have to but feel it is a cancer on this site to downvote without explanation. The question provides no example, no research not understood, anything whatsoever referring to the effort of the OP. This question is simply not suitable for a forum of CODE based questions. Now if the OP amended the question to meet any of these criteria, I will change my position. If he/she doesn't, then neither will I.

Comment: @nameless css I added worked in firefox